# jQuery event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was studying a colleague's code and I noticed an event that I haven't used before and I can't find it online either.

This is the code:

```
$('body').on('items-set', function(){
    bindDropdown();
    console.log('must bind event')
})
```

That console log never runs, I don't see the message in the console. What does 'items-set' mean?

Comment: That looks like a custom even that your colleague either forgot to use or forgot to delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely a custom event, triggered by the following code.

```
$('body').trigger('items-set');
```

Comment: Nope, no trigger on that event in any of the js files associated with the project.

Comment: Found a trigger in a <script> tag inside a php file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

'items-set' is not a standard javascript/jquery event. Most likely it is either a custom event created by the user or of some library that is included in the page.

And the obvious reason I can think of for the console.log not being called is that the event is not triggered..

Also, if you cant find the custom event declaration anywhere, could be a 'stray' segment of code that the developer forgot to delete and which doesn't really do anything?

Answer (score -1):

correct is 3 parameters of [$.on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('body').on(EVENT_HERE, SELECTOR_HERE, function(){
    bindDropdown();
    console.log('must bind event')
})
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with this, it works with 2 parameters too, see codepen. http://codepen.io/Radu/pen/tCuBE